# mobile.changePage() not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I made a simple code to create a "Splash screen".

I'm using `localstorage` for my data. If I load it for the first time, I get data from URL and I can change page using `$.mobile.changePage()`. But if `localstorage` data already stored, changing page code doesn't work.

```
function HOME() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('newhome')) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#pageone", {
            transition: "none",
            changeHash: false
        });
    } else {
        $.get('http:/someurl', function (data) { //comment this line if we make apk
            window.localStorage.setItem('newhome', JSON.stringify(data));
        }).done(function (data) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#pageone", {
                transition: "none",
                changeHash: false
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```
<body>
  <div id="splash" data-role="page"><h1>splash here</h1></div>
  <div id="pageone" data-role="page"><p>my content here</p></div>
</body>
```

If I run different functions e.g. `console.log`, they work, but not `$.mobile.changePage`.

Comment: fixing this by adding setTimeOut 1 second.

Comment: Is this being called inside an event handler?

Comment: it depends when do you call `HOME()` function. Once jQM is initalized, it will take you directly to first _page div_ in DOM.

Comment: @Omar and what need to do for correct way ? tell me please

Comment: @Omar at current time, some times (but not always it's still return to first div. meanwhile i set time 3seconds.

Comment: @peter You should call event.preventDefault() in your event handler and then you should not have to do this inside a setTimeout

Comment: @unobf bro, tell me please where i must put this. PLEASEeeee

Comment: What do you mean by _current time_?

Comment: @peter - to tell you where to put it, you must show me more code. Where are you registering the event handler? Where is the event object available and what does the event handler do other than call HOME? Also, I have always used jQuery.mobile.navigate('#pageone') instead of pageChange.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your page doesn't change is because it never enters the if loop. The else is executed yes, but the method `.getItem()` does **not** return a *Boolean* type. to check that your key is actually set you should check against null. So your code would look a bit more like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("username") === null) {
$.get('http://www.thejewishinsights.com/wp/wp-json/posts', function (data) { //comment this line if we make apk
        window.localStorage.setItem('newhome', JSON.stringify(data));
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#pageone", {
            transition: "none",
            changeHash: false
        });
    });
}
else{
$.mobile.changePage("#pageone", {
        transition: "none",
        changeHash: false
    });
}
```

I didn't check the code but you should get the idea. Also i would advise against `.changePage` as it will be removed from jQuery mobile 1.5 as stated in their documentation http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

I hope This helps. 
Cheers and happy new year!

Comment: u not reading ?  code work correct. im always was in this func

Comment: I have no idea what the rest of you code outside looks like, so the only thing i can conclude is that you should use another approach to change between pages. I will be easier than figuring out where you went wrong.

Comment: I think you were a bit rude... think he was trying to help you, so telling "u not reading?" make other think twice about helping you...

Comment: I have no idea why I was down voted. Your question is unclear? I can not guess the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this:?

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change","#newpage");
```

I think that JQMobile Official Site recommend using this instead of the one you use.

Comment: yes, still works, but I used to have many problems with changePage and with this new approach, none... so I think maybe it solves his problem.